# print out a geometric shape (my case is a rectagular) , with the frame "*" and inside "Q"

Tags: java

```
public void Esercizio8(){
    int alt = 5;
    int base= 10;

    for(int i=0; i<alt; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<base; j++) {

            if (i==1 && j==1) {
                System.out.print("Q");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to go ahead, and if I run this, it appears only `*` and one `Q`

Comment: whare the 'Q' have to place inside? Is in in the exact middle, or simply the inside of the frame?

Comment: like this for example

Comment: ***********
*QQQQQQQQQ*
*QQQQQQQQQ*
*QQQQQQQQQ*
***********

Comment: sorry but i mean, for line 2 and column 2 print Q, for line 3 and column 3 print Q etc.. but the frame all with *

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is so, you are expected to spend some time thinking about the solution and hopefully come up with one by yourself. However hard it might seem, it's the only way to really learn what you are doing. While Stack Overflow does not prohibit posting hw related questions, asking somebody to give you the solution is terribly wrong and hinders your learning process.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of leaving comments

Comment: Please print the expected output in the question :)

Comment: you are perfectly right, but I already thought about this prolem all the afternoon, and the code that I wrote there was just to make the people understand the problem, I changed it so many time that I just wrote a faster one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
public void Esercizio8(){ 
    int alt = 5; 
    int base= 10;

    for(int i=0; i<alt; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<base; j++) {

            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == alt-1 || j == base-1)
                System.out.print("*");
            else    
                System.out.print("Q");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Your main issue was that your newline was inside the second for loop. Other than that, your conditional was wrong too; mine is a bit rough but accurate i think